# Subsorting list of mappings

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, mapping

I have a mapping like the following

```
mapping = [
    "key1",
    "key2",
    "key3",
    "key4",
    "key5#1",
    "key5#4",
    "key5#2",
    "key5#3",
    "key6#1",
    "key6#2"
]
```

and a list of lists, e.g. `[['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9' 'val10']]` and I want to end up with a list of dictionaries, e.g.

```
[{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    "key4": "val4",
    "key5": ["val5", "val7", "val8", "val6"],
    "key6": ["val9", "val10"],
}]
```

Such that each key without a `#` just have 1 value, whereas keys with `#` have an ordered list sorted by the integer after `#`. What I have now is:

```
for i in range(len(mapping)):
    if '#' in mapping[i]:
        result.setdefault(mapping[i].split('#')[0], []).append(row[i])
    else:
        result[mapping[i]] = row[i]
```

However, this does not sort the values according to the number after `#`.

Comment: Does the order after # is import or applying a sort will be enought at the end?

Comment: It should be sorted on the integer after `#` and not the corresponding value

Comment: Thought you could do this, but not... It depends on order of comming element
result.setdefault(mysplit[0], []).insert(mysplit[1]-1, row[i])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` here. The idea is to create a dict using the keys from mapping and initially each key will be initialized to a list of `None`'s of the size of number of repetitions of a key.

```
from itertools import groupby
dct = {}
for k, g in groupby(mapping, lambda x: x.split('#')[0]):
    length = sum(1 for _ in g)
    dct[k] = [None] * length
...
```

Now `dct` looks like:

```
>>> dct
{'key3': [None],
 'key2': [None],
 'key1': [None],
 'key6': [None, None],
 'key5': [None, None, None, None],
 'key4': [None]}
```

Note that if mapping isn't sorted already then we can sort it using: `mapping.sort(key=lambda x: x.split('#')[0])`. This will group similar keys together.

The above thing can also be done by first identifying count of each key first followed by initialization of `dict` using the count. This way it can be done in O(N) time in case similar keys in `mapping` are not grouped already.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dct = {k: [None] * v  for k, v in Counter(
        key.split('#')[0] for key in mapping).items()}
```

Now we can loop over mapping and the list and update values in `dct` accordingly:

```
for key, value in zip(mapping, lst[0]):
    if '#' not in key:
        dct[key] = value
    else:
        key, index = key.split('#')
        # Simply assign the value to the index 
        dct[key][int(index)-1] = value
...
>>> dct
{'key3': 'val3',
 'key2': 'val2',
 'key1': 'val1',
 'key6': ['val9', 'val10'],
 'key5': ['val5', 'val7', 'val8', 'val6'],
 'key4': 'val4'}
```

Comment: If I sort mapping, then it would be hard to identify the mapping to the other lists, wouldn't it?

Comment: @YnkDK Did you mean order in the output dict?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I have tested it with `groupby` as suggested first. What is the benefit of using `Counter`?

Comment: @YnkDK With `Counter()` we won't need a sorted list in case the items with similar keys weren't grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
for i, key in enumerate(mapping):
    if '#' in key:
        key, order = key.split('#')
        result.setdefault(key, []).insert(int(order) - 1, row[i])
    else:
        result[key] = row[i]
```

Notes:

1. Use `enumerate` - `for i in range(len(something))` is considered a bad habit
2. Casting `order` to `int` is required in Python3 - insert takes an int, a string won't work.

Comment: You cannot if last element came first you will not be able to add it (out of range)

Comment: It seems like @Destrif is right. If I try `key5#4, key5#3, key5#2, key5#1` I do not get the correct order

Comment: You're right! Leaving my answer as a warning for others not to repeat my mistakes - as others are saying, `itertools.groupby` seems to be the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `groupby` and list slicing. Note that you’re missing a comma in `row` after `val9`.

```
def split_key(k):
    if '#' in k:
        return k.split('#')[0]
    else:
        return k

def group_keys(keys):
    for K, G in groupby(keys, key=split_key):
        yield split_key(K), sum(1 for g in G)

def slice_row(mapping, row):
    i = 0
    for key, length in group_keys(mapping):
        if length == 1:
            yield key, row[i]
        else:
            yield key, row[i:i + length]
        i += length

print(dict(slice_row(mapping, row[0])))

# >>> {'key4': 'val4', 'key6': ['val9', 'val10'], 'key5': ['val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8'], 'key3': 'val3', 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
```